# create sub lists by grouping with conditional check on two consecutive zeros

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list:

```
lst = [0, -7, 0, 0, -8, 0, 0, -4, 0, 0, 0, -6, 0, -4, -29, -10, 0, -16, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 18, -1, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 10, -10, 0, -12, 3, -5, -10]
```

I want to create group of sublists with conditional break when a value is followed by two consecutive zeros.

so my intermediate list would like

```
newlst = [-7,-8,-4,[-6,-4,-29,-10,-16],[2,3,18,-1,-2],[21,10,-10,-12,3,-5,-10]]
```

whereas the final output will be sum of sublists:

```
[-7,-8,-4,-65,18,-3]
```

I tried using the index number in a for loop with enumerate but i'm not getting my desired output.

Comment: Do you actually want the intermediate, or only the final?

Comment: final output is what i'm looking for.

Comment: What sort of value range is possible here? Are they all two digits or less? There are some more clever tricks you can use here if so.

Comment: Final should be `[-7, -8, -4, -65, 20, -3]`, right?

Comment: yes. i think i made a mistake in sum.

Answer (score 6):

I group pairs of adjacent numbers by whether they hold any truth. Then take the truthy groups and sum them. Might be a bit too complicated, but I like using the `any` key.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [sum(a for a, _ in g) for k, g in groupby(zip(lst, lst[1:] + [0]), any) if k]
[-7, -8, -4, -65, 20, -3]
```

(Thanks to blhsing and ShadowRanger for improvements.)

Bit shorter way to turn the pairs back into singles (first is Python 2, second is Python 3):

```
>>> [sum(zip(*g)[0]) for k, g in groupby(zip(lst, lst[1:] + [0]), any) if k]
>>> [sum(next(zip(*g))) for k, g in groupby(zip(lst, lst[1:] + [0]), any) if k]
```

Comment: Ooh, nice. I'm a big fan of `groupby`, but didn't see an obvious way to use it here. Happy someone figured it out.

Comment: Great answer! However, you're incorrectly ditching the first element of `lst` by using `for _, g` instead of `for g, _`, so if `lst` hadn't happened to start with a 0 your result would've been wrong.

Comment: @blhsing: You're not understanding how `groupby` works. `g` is the iterator containing all the pairs where are least one element of the pair was non-zero, the first element (`_`, which we ignore) of the `tuple`s yielded by `groupby` is just the key value associated with that group (which is just going to be `True` or `False` since the `key` function is `any`). It works just fine if you pop off the leading `0` from `lst` because it doesn't depend on that at all.

Comment: Minor optimization: I think you can avoid the `if g` check in the `sum`ing list comprehension if you test `if _` in the `tmp` genexpr (or for readability): `tmp = ([a for a, _ in g if a] for nonzero, g in groupby(zip(lst, lst[1:] + [0]), any) if nonzero)` Saves the expense of the inner list comprehension (and rapidly skips the zero group) when you know you're in a group of double NULs anyway.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Sorry I was indeed horribly mistaken. Thanks for the insights.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yeah I just realized that when I saw blhsing's comment. And I went even further, now it's a decent one-liner :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann: :-) Technically, the `if a` isn't necessary either, it just saves `sum` a little work to avoid adding `0`s to the sum (but does more work in the genexpr, which probably costs more). `sum(map(itemgetter(0), g))` would do it (with `from operator import itemgetter`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ah, right, don't need that anymore. Thanks. I don't like itemgetter here, just makes it longer and more complicated.

Comment: @blhsing While you were mistaken, you made me aware of a wasted opportunity, now leading to a much neater solution. So thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with a `for` loop:

```
zeros = 0
result = [0]

for i in lst:
    if i == 0:
        zeros += 1

    elif zeros >= 2:                # if there are more than two zeros, append the new 
                                    # element to the result
        result.append(i)
        zeros = 0

    else:                           # Otherwise add it to the last element
        result[-1] += i
        zeros = 0

result
# [-7, -8, -4, -65, 20, -3]
```

To get the corresponding index, you can use `enumerate`:

```
zeros = 0
reSum = [0]
reInd = [[]]
for i, v in enumerate(lst):
    if v == 0:
        zeros += 1
    elif zeros >= 2:
        zeros = 0
        reSum.append(v)
        reInd.append([i])
​
    else:
        zeros = 0
        reSum[-1] += v
        reInd[-1] += [i]

reSum
# [-7, -8, -4, -65, 20, -3]

reInd
# [[1],
#  [4],
#  [7],
#  [11, 13, 14, 15, 17],
#  [20, 21, 23, 24, 25],
#  [32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39]]
```

Comment: Might be wrong, for example if `lst` is empty. I'd start with `result = []` and `zeros = 2`.

Comment: is it possible to get the index and append it to the seperate list?? using enumerate and storing all the index's of the numbers including index's of the group list??

Comment: Yeah, you can use enumerate to get the corresponding index. See the update.

Comment: @StefanPochmann For case where `lst` is empty, I think it may be better to check as an edge case. For `result = []` it suits the case when `lst` starts with two or more zeros, but an extra `0` shouldn't affect the result that much, or it can be checked as another edge case as well, which I believe OP should be able to take care of in reality.

Answer (score 0):

Cheesy solution if your values all occur in `range(-128, 128)` is to use the `split` and `replace` methods of `bytearray` (which conveniently converts to and from `int`) to do the splitting:

```
lst = [0, -7, 0, 0, -8, 0, 0, -4, 0, 0, 0, -6, 0, -4, -29, -10, 0, -16, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 18, -1, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 10, -10, 0, -12, 3, -5, -10]

# Adjust all  values up by 0x80 so they fall in bytearray's expected 0-255 range
bts = bytearray(x + 0x80 for x in lst)

# Split on double \x80 (the value of 0 after adjustment)
# then remove single \x80 from each part
parts = [b.replace(b'\x80', b'') for b in bts.split(b'\x80\x80')]

# Undo adjustment and unpack (and filter empty sublists out completely)
newlst = [b[0] - 0x80 if len(b) == 1 else [x - 0x80 for x in b] for b in parts if b]

# Or to just get the sums, no need to create newlst, just filter and sum en masse:
sums = [sum(b) - 0x80 * len(b) for b in parts if b]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = lst = [0, -7, 0, 0, -8, 0, 0, -4, 0, 0, 0, -6, 0, -4, -29, -10, 0, -16, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 18, -1, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 10, -10, 0, -12, 3, -5, -10]
lastElement = None
new_list=[]
sub_list=[]
for element in list:
    if element == 0 == lastElement:
        if sub_list == []:
            continue
        new_list.append(sub_list)
        sub_list = []
    elif element == 0:
        pass
    else:
        sub_list.append(element)
    lastElement = element
new_list.append(sub_list)
print(new_list)
[[-7], [-8], [-4], [-6, -4, -29, -10, -16], [2, 3, 18, -1, -2], [21, 10, -10, -12, 3, -5, -10]]
```

Comment: Don't post answers as images. Post the code here, as text (if you type it in here, select the code block, and hit `Ctrl-k`, it will indent and auto-highlight as a formatted code block on post).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I really don't even get why people would go to the effort of taking a photo of their code, instead of just copy'n pastin'.

Comment: Relax, I was on my phone and did not know how to write in code format. So I took a screenshot of my cell phone. Doesn't need to give a thumb down for that, the solution is still a valid one. Sorry if that "offend" you in any possible way.

Answer (score 0):

```
map(lambda x:eval(re.sub('^,','',x,1).replace(',','+')) if(len(x))>3 else eval(x.replace(',','+')),filter(lambda x:x!=',0',re.split(r',0,0,|\|',"|".join(re.split(r'(,0){3,}',l)))))
```